# Attribute "calculation" with value "DistinctCount" must have a value from the list

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i have put variable 'distinct count'. when i want to run into application the warning message appear and show the
'Attribute "calculation" with value "DistinctCount" must have a value from the list "Nothing Count Sum Average Lowest Highest StandardDeviation Variance System ".

Why this happened?. anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Distinct count was introduced to the iReport in the JR Version 1.2.4 . I smell the problem is, you are using an older JR jar. Upgrading your jasperreports.jar might clear your problem.

Comment: i'm using ireport 2.0.2. How to upgrade the jar?.which version is available?

Comment: You could use anything greater than the version 1.2.3. The file will be available under the folder "/iReport-(your version)/lib". Also you need to deploy the same jar in the web application you are using..
Hope this helps..!